# Set selected navigation option using window.location

Tags: javascript

I have a theme that sets the selected left navigation option based on what URL you are visiting. However, it breaks if the is a variable attached to the URL, for example `www.test.com/abc.aspx?delete=1`. The URL `www.test.com/abc.aspx` works fine and sets the link ABC to active.

I have tried to modify the code to cut off everything after and including `?`, but it won't work as intended (nothing in the NAV is selected).

ORIGINAL CODE:

```
$(function () {
    var url = window.location;
    var element = $('ul#sidebarnav a').filter(function () {
        return this.href == url;
    }).addClass('active').parent().addClass('active');
    while (true) {
        if (element.is('li')) {
            element = element.parent().addClass('in').parent().addClass('active');
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }

});
```

MY EDITED CODE:

```
$(function () {
    var url = window.location.toString();
    var url_fix = url.split('?');
    var element = $('ul#sidebarnav a').filter(function () {
        return this.href == url_fix[0];
    }).addClass('active').parent().addClass('active');
    while (true) {
        if (element.is('li')) {
            element = element.parent().addClass('in').parent().addClass('active');
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

I think it is the line with "return this.href == url_fix[0];" that is the culprit.

SOLUTION (what I came up with after reading the comments, thanks guys):

```
$(function () {
    var url = location.href.split("/").slice(-1).toString();
    var url_fix = url.split('?');
    var element = $('ul#sidebarnav a').filter(function () {
        return $(this).attr("href") == url_fix[0];
    }).addClass('active').parent().addClass('active');
    while (true) {
        if (element.is('li')) {
            element = element.parent().addClass('in').parent().addClass('active');
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: yea `this` isn't what you expect.

Comment: Care to elaborate?

Comment: Instead of `return this.href == url_fix[0];` try using `return $(this).attr("href") == url_fix[0];`

Comment: I don't see any issue with your code.  Does it make a difference if you do `return this.href.toUpperCase() == url_fix[0].toUpperCase();`?

Comment: Used the answer from @vbguyny to solve the issue, thanks!

Comment: Thanks @RickHitchcock! Could you please mark my comment as the answer so that it could help others in the future? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the answer by @vbguyny to solve the issue. Had to add location.href.split("/").slice(-1).toString(); to get the actual page name, but after that it worked fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try comparing `pathname`s instead.

```
var element = $('ul#sidebarnav a').filter(function () {
    return this.pathname == location.pathname;
}).addClass('active').parent().addClass('active');
```

For example on this page `location.pathname` returns:

```
"/questions/48234042/set-selected-navigation-option-using-window-locaiton/48234196"
```

and does not include `location.hash` or `location.search`

Comment: This is a good solution.  Do you think the original problem may be due to comparing absolute with relative pathnames?

Comment: @RickHitchcock really not sure. `this.href` returns absolute url with protocol and domain so generally should match. Hard to tell without seeing more of the real world examples

Comment: This for some reason didnt work, I also thought it was the most viable answer.